# Double input prompt() in javascript (semi-duplicate)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, http

I would like to add the functionality of sites like https://edu.klockars.com/, https://math.reves.cl/, and https://www.w3.org/2002/ with their double input `prompt()`.
I have noticed this on multiple other sites too but I cant seem to find the correct code that adds it.

But while searching through the code while scraping the sites, the closest thing I could find is a jquery code that has a small resemblance to what the `prompt()` code might be.

To my knowledge this should not be possible, so it makes me wonder if its a host/server script from cloudflare or something because it also triggers in view-source.

I am truly stumped as this is should not be possible and makes it so you cant even see the code without intensive amounts of effort. I have looked for the code for about 6 months now (not actively) and even used chatGPT to maybe find the script. When I have used chatGPT it usually gives me jquery code, but i have looked through the [documentations](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) multiple times and cant find anything.

This code would be really helpful, regards: a very desperate person.

Additional notes and edits:

1. I have seen the same thing on a random cyber security test online before.
2. When trying to save in the wayback machine, it yields a 401 error (unauthorized).
3. Using `fetch()` does nothing.

Similar posts:

[Is there any way to create prompt with two input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994208/is-there-any-way-to-create-prompt-with-two-input-fields)

[I am working in a javascript and I want to create two input field in s single prompt in javascript, how its possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644082/i-am-working-in-a-javascript-and-i-want-to-create-two-input-field-in-s-single-pr)

[Is there any way to make a double-input-prompt box in javascript? (With Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222095/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-double-input-prompt-box-in-javascript-with-example)

Comment: This is just Basic Authentication set up on the site. There is no JS code that shows the credentials screen, it's part of the browser implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) and is triggered by the server sending a [`401 Unauthorized`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) status with a [`WWW-Authenticate` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) with the value `Basic`.

When credentials are entered, the browser will repeat the previous request with the addition of a `Authorization: Basic <credentials>` header.

It has nothing to do with JavaScript, forms, jQuery, or HTML and can't be replicated using any of those.